# OAuth2Parameters could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to use OAuth 2.0 for authorizing google docs API,
According to the example given by google at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20
they are using the piece of code:

```
// OAuth2Parameters holds all the parameters related to OAuth 2.0.
      OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();

      // Set your OAuth 2.0 Client Id (which you can register at
      // https://code.google.com/apis/console).
      parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID;

      // Set your OAuth 2.0 Client Secret, which can be obtained at
      // https://code.google.com/apis/console.
      parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;

      // Set your Redirect URI, which can be registered at
      // https://code.google.com/apis/console.
      parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI;

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      // STEP 3: Get the Authorization URL
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      // Set the scope for this particular service.
      parameters.Scope = SCOPE;

      // Get the authorization url.  The user of your application must visit
      // this url in order to authorize with Google.  If you are building a
      // browser-based application, you can redirect the user to the authorization
      // url.
      string authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
```

Problem is that when I try to use this code it says that OAuth2Parameters couldn't be found
I'm using both `Google.GData.Client`; & `Google.GData.Documents`;

What to do here??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the `OAuth2Parameters` class you have to checkout the source of the library and build it yourself:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/checkout

That class will be included in the upcoming version 2.0 of the library.